# Qt ignores const specifier

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, constants

I've created simple snippet to show strange behavior I noticed. That's it:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QLineEdit>

class MyObject : public QWidget
{
public:
    explicit MyObject(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent) {
        editor = new QLineEdit(this);
    }

    void setValue(const QString &s) const {
        editor->setText(s);
        editor->setReadOnly(true);
        editor->setMaxLength(s.length());
    }

private:
    QLineEdit *editor;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    return app.exec();
}
```

`MyObject::setValue` function has `const` specifier, but this code is compiled well. Note that `setText`, `setReadOnly` and `setMaxLength` functions aren't `const`:

```
void setText(const QString &);
void setReadOnly(bool);
void setMaxLength(int);
```

I just want to know what causes such behavior?
I use Qt 4.7.4 with MingGW 4.6.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(This is not Qt related. This is a general C++ question.)

The compiler is correct, because you are not modifying `editor`. What you are modifying is `*editor`; you are only modifying the object it points to. The `const` specifier will only disallow changing members directly contained in the object. The object `editor` points to is not a member and thus can be modified:

```
void setValue(const QString &s) const {
    editor->setText(s); // OK
    editor = new QLineEdit; // Error: 'editor' is changed.
}
```

Comment: Ouch! How can I missed that? :)

Answer (score 0):

By the way there are two ways of seeing the constness of a method:

- *Bitwise constness* or *physical constness* if the member function doesn't modify any of the object's data member (excluding static ones)
- *Logical constness* doesn't allow any change even for the objects pointed.

Compilers only detect the first type of constness, as you experienced :)

This is discussed in one of the items in Effective C++ written by Scott Meyers